# How can I set Cookies to GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, guzzle

How can I use GuzzleHttp to get page content by sending a request with custom cookies?

Comment: Unfairly closed cause it is a legit question. The documentation is lacking on this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a cookie jar:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();

$jar->setCookie(new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SetCookie([
    'Name'     => ...,
    'Value'    => ...,
    'Domain'   => ...,
    'Path'     => '/',
    'Max-Age'  => ...,
    'Expires'  => ...,
    'Secure'   => ...,
    'Discard'  => ...,
    'HttpOnly' => ...
]));
$client->request('GET', '/get', ['cookies' => $jar]);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cookies

Comment: Hey, Do you have any knowledge of using bypass Cloudflare?